# How to experience full PS:T experience?

Tags: planescape-torment

I want to experience PS:T because of the story. I am, however, short of patience for gaming nowadays so I found what seems to be the best novelization around. I feel in my gut I should play the actual game though, which I already bought some months ago and stopped playing after 30 min, because I do not have the patience for the combat mechanics.

To decide, I want to know:
 - can I experience the story as in the novella with one run-through ? (which should I do, I'll cheat and also play on Easy as a means to not get bothered by combat) ?
 - if so, will it require me to go and chat with *every NPC just because 'what if he has something to say?'* ?

I remember fondly of playing BGII:SoA, but I know that if I'm required to explore all the NPC's and handle inventory I'll end up not playing the game. I do expect to read a lot, but not to pixel hunt and do inventory management.

This question of course was also born of a fear of the novella being incomplete in relation to the game, though it doesn't seem that way.

Link to the stuff I found: http://discogenie.dyndns.org/planescape/

What I really want to know: can I play for the story without getting bothered by game mechanics ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. But you *can* sit back and let someone else handle the mechanics for you, by watching a [Let's Play series](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5EE0AA3B5A9E2ADB).

All the story, none of the fuss; and you can think of each one as watching a TV episode, which always somehow makes the time it takes feel more appropriate to me. You can be sure that a lot of people who missed Torment the first time around are doing the same in anticipation of Numenara.

Comment: Oh, I had discarded LP series but the way you put it, it's actually a good idea, thanks. It seems though, the one linked above has no end yet, so I found another here: http://youtu.be/RWWVLnQ39Kk

Answer (score 2):

A trick I used in the past, when I was out for stories rather than challenges, is to use cheats and a guide/FAQ. Cheats remove the challenge from mechanics, such as fights, and the guide removes the challenge of knowing where to go and what to do. All of this while retaining some interactivity.

Also, if you suddenly want more freedom, you can save the game, try something (such as a different dialogue path) and then reload to keep following the guide.

GameFAQs has [this guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/187975-planescape-torment/faqs/7964) which is particularly detailed and even has tricks to avoid combats in some of the more combat-oriented zones of the game.

Sorcerer's Place has [a save editor and a trainer](http://www.sorcerers.net/Games/Torment/index_editors.php) which would help you from dying in fights, though it won't win them for you. I tested *Torment Savegame Editor* with success. *Torment Trainer* crashed on me, sadly.

There is also the [Infinity Engine Save Editor](http://www.sorcerers.net/Games/IEmodding/IESE.php) which works for the Baldur's Gate and Icewind Dale series as well as PS:T. I gave a quick test and it seems to work fine.

If editing your save, I'd suggest giving yourself 25 in all abilities (Strength, Dexterity, ...) and a high number of Maximum HP (say, more than 500). This will give you some regenerating ability and quite an edge against whatever you face, whether in combat or dialogues. You may want to do the same with any companions joining you, and possibly update Hit Points values if it turns out you need more.